# getting an error while subscribing an object in sf to sf connection

Tags: connection

I have established a sf to sf connection between two orgs, 
Org 1 Published, Org 2 Subscribed
Org 2 Published,
during Org 1 Subscribe
 error
 **An internal server error has occurred.**

Please help.

Connection Mapping: Lead Object

Comment: You'll need to open a case with Salesforce.

Comment: reduce the scope of the issue to just the default Lead fields used in S2S, then add in new lead fields until you get the error